# Ubuntu screen doesn't turn on after suspend, using dell inspiron 15 7559 with Ubuntu 16.04.3

Tags: 16.04, dell, screen

Recently I install ubuntu in my lap, and have that issue, my kernel version is 4.10. Also the brightness of the screen cannot be changed.

Comment: Do you have an NVMe M.2 Gen 3.0 x 4 SSD?

Comment: No, just an HDD